# How to use avro with HBase 0.96.0+?

Tags: hbase, avro

My project is integrating with another projects using Avro. The project started using HBase and it would be useful to use some HBase Avro API but according to [HBASE-6653](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6553) avro gateway support has been removed in HBase 0.96.0.
Is it possible to find this gateway anywhere in opensource lands? I was digging into github and *.apache.org but didn't found anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found acceptable using [kiji](http://www.kiji.org/) for serializing Avro in HBase.
In addition kiji has many useful tools, for example, awesome schema (layout) management instruments.